# Set different color for each bars using ChartJS in Angular 4

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm very new to angular and I'm using ChartJS to plot a bar graph in my Angular 4 application. I want different colors for each bars. I did like what they say here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/, but its not wokring

Here's my html file:

```
<div>
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas class="dashboard-tile-chart" baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts file

```
export class BarGraphComponent implements OnInit {

  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false
      }]
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: string[] = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
  public barChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = false;

  public barChartData: any[] = [
      {
        data: [100, 150, 150, 100, 200, 150, 100],
        label: '',
        backgroundColor: [
          '#5cb85c',
          '#65C6BB',
          '#1BBC9B',
          '#f0ad4e',
          '#5cb85c',
          '#5cb85c',
          '#f0ad4e'
        ]
      }];
}
```

data is showing, but different colors are not set for each bars.

Other similar topics on stackoverflow says to do like this:

```
myObjBar.datasets[0].bars[0].fillColor = "green"; //bar 1
myObjBar.datasets[0].bars[1].fillColor = "orange"; //bar 2
```

but I don't have an object of the barchart.

**Edit:**

How do I set the bar color dynamically? I tried:

```
const colors = [];
this.vitalValues.forEach(value => {
  colors.push(value.color);
});

const barColors: Array<any> = [{
  backgroundColor: colors
}];

this.barChartColors = barColors;
```

but no effect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY using the following ...

In your HTML, add **`[colors]`** directive ...

```
<div>
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas class="dashboard-tile-chart" baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [colors]="barChartColors"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

then, in your **`component.ts`** , add ...

```
public barChartColors:Array<any> = [{
   backgroundColor: ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange']
}];
```

<sub>not an 'Angular 4' pro but AFAIK this should work</sub>

Comment: Many thanks. I've been stuck with this thing for an hour.

Comment: Also how do I set the colors dynamically. Please see my edit

Comment: That's a diff. question bro *(+ not related with chartjs. typical angular 4 question)*, and I don't have that much knowledge about Angular 4, so I can't give you a proper solution. You should rather ask a new question for that.